# How to read & write in a properties file with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, properties-file, read-write

I'm working in a JEE web project. I would like to read and write into a properties file which is located into WebContent/WEB-INF/classes folder.

How can I do this via JavaScript on the client side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an endpoint that the JavaScript code can post to via [Ajax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX), and have servlet code handle the post by updating the properties file.